# Open Google Trip Planner Dynamic URL results inside a wordpress page and not a new window

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, google-maps

I am using a Google Trip Planner for a transit website but the results open up a new window with the trip plotted on a google map.

Unlike this post:
[Opening a dynamically built Google URL in new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436723/opening-a-dynamically-built-google-url-in-new-window)

I am looking for the results of the dynamically-created url to open into an existing page inside my Wordpress site.

Here is the code for the button:

`<input value="Let's Go!" onclick="return buildURL();" type="button" >`

Any help would be great.

Comment: At the end of the buildURL() function, setting "window.location.href=" to the new URL should open it in the current window.